# is there is an function call bip its not call the function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to call the function inside the jquery but, not able to call its showing error as "function is not define"

```js
var counter = 30;
var intervalId = null;
intervalId = setInterval("bip()", 1000);
setTimeout("action()", counter * 1000);

function action() {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
}

function bip() {
  if (counter == 0) {
    console.log("true");
  } else {
    counter--;
  }
}
```

Inside action is started counter will start running if the counter is 0 it will return alert true

Comment: Sounds like `bip` is not on the top level. Pass the function itself, not a *string* containing it (that's like `eval`)

Comment: The code that you posted **works** and does not produce "function is not defined", so your actual code is different from what you posted. (And a note: maybe you should make the `setTimeout` delay a bit longer before clearing the interval.)

Comment: @peter B in Mozilla Firefox 42.0 browser. the code is not working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing string instead of function into `setInterval` and `setTimeout`. Change that like below.

```
setInterval(function(){ bip() }, 1000);
setTimeout(function(){action()}, counter * 1000);
```

Comment: Both `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` accept a string argument which gets run through `eval()`, so the OPs logic would be fine (although not exactly best practice). As such this issue would appear to be a scope problem, not a syntax one. Also note that if it was a syntax problem the best solution would be to pass the function reference, not create a verbose anonymous function, ie. `setInterval(bip, 1000);`

Comment: In other browsers its working fine.in Mozilla Firefox showing Error "bib is not define".